# Hibernate jpa "mappedBy" exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

i have problem with my JPA database when i wanted add new UserDetails object to my database using persist method. Then i got exception: "duplicate entry 2 for key hibernate" this exception was related to Product class. I found solution based on adding mappedBy parameter to @OneToMany (above Product class list) but then i got "mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property"
Is there any solution?

```
@Entity
public class UserDetails {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

....
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private UserOffer userOffer;
..... 
//getters and setters
```

next

```
@Entity
public class UserOffer {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

.....
@OneToOne(cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
private DetailsOffer detailsOffer;
.....
```

next

```
@Entity
public class DetailsOffer {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="detailsOffer")
private List<Product> products;
```

nexr
    @Entity
    public class Product {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

private PetType petType;
private int petNumber;
@ElementCollection
private List<String> goodies;
private String petDescribtion;
private BigDecimal price;
```

Error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.knr.domain_ver2.Product.detailsOffer in com.knr.domain_ver2.DetailsOffer.products
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:769) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:719) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1655) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1623) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:278) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:847) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:874) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:360) ~[spring-orm-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:382) ~[spring-orm-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:371) ~[spring-orm-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336) ~[spring-orm-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Can you post the code to the `Product` class also? This sounds like you may need to delete your database and re-insert your items.

Comment: since you dont appear to have a `mappedBy` set, and you likely should have, perhaps you should clarify what you really have, and what exception+stack trace you got

Comment: I have edited it.

Comment: and are you going to tell us what your `mappedBy` setting is?

Comment: ok, i have added it.

Comment: MappedBy means this is a bidirectional relation, so this field in the related class points back to this field.byou dont have that field in Product!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In class `Product` you need to declare the field `detailsOffer` and map it as `@ManyToOne` and `@JoinColumn` with the column name that refers to `DetailsOffer`.

For example:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = 'id_details_offer')
private DetailsOffer detailsOffer;
```

I hope it helps you.